# PHP making my own keywords for a product and match it to the entered value in the search field

Tags: php, html, forms

I am creating a search field for my website.
I have keywords for every "product" and I want to direct to their URL  IF the entered value matches my keywords and ELSE redirect it to another page.

```
<form action="redirect.php" > 
<input id="search" name="search" type="text" value="Search Here" />
<input name="submit" type="button" value="Go" />
</form>
```

The function I want :

```
<?php


if (isset($_GET['submit']));

$product1_keywords = "animal feeds, "weanrite, "Wean Rite;
$searchValue = $_POST['search'];



if ($search_fieldValue = $product1_keywords) {


header('Location: http://localhost/equalivet_2/#products/wean_rite.html');
}

else {

// Redirect page
header('Location: http://localhost/equalivet_2/not_found.html');
}

?>
```

Do I have to make a database to pre-define my keywords or a simple PHP will do?

Can anyone help me with this?

Your help will be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define an anchor tag in your html and your URL should point to the name of the anchor which is 
yourpage.html#anchortagid

html

```
<div id="container" style="width:300px; height:300px">
    <a id="a1" name="a1"></a>
</div>
```

php

instead of using go to try redirect with the anchor in the end

```
products/product1.html#a1
```

that will automatically take you to a1 anchor

Comment: hmmm .. your right. Now I was thinking that instead of loading it into a <div>, I should use redirect method... By the way, could you give me the php syntax for redirecting to a URL after submit? Thanks!

Comment: may be this will help http://php.about.com/od/learnphp/ht/phpredirection.htm , dont forget to give me an upvote or mark my answer as right if it solved your problem

Comment: yeh but you got to do this in php in the place where you have goto

Comment: ok whats the error you getting now ? an upvote would motivate me

Comment: im sorry if you are looking at loading dynamic content on div, then what you are trying will not work. you have to do it on the client side instead of server, your redirect stuff will not work here in this scenario.

Comment: did you get it from this place http://css-tricks.com/dynamic-page-replacing-content/ ?

Comment: yes but i not using that in this search form anymore.. I'll use redirect method of php

Comment: @ Chandra .. I've changed my question, maybe you could help  me now. thanks